# Make an Anchor Tag not fade out in a slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get an anchor tag(button) not to fade in and out of a slide.
http://demo.gbaus.com/index.html
The Get Quote button on the Home Page I want to stay visible at all times when changing through slides.  Is this even possible?

Comment: show some code and specify what is't working is should.

Comment: I dont even know where to start.  I tried some stuff with css but did nothing I think it has to do with JS which im not familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you trying to do

If it's about the location yes , It's possible, U should consider them as the positioned elements

give position absolute to them and place them On the Slider so they never move

but if you try to go to other pages and want to keep those elements on the page you shoud use something like HTML5 push state

provide more Information

Comment: All I want is for the Get Quote button not to fade in and out.  Just want it visible at all times.

Comment: you have THREE GET A QUOTE (A tags) and you fade The parent so It disapears each time

Comment: you should move get a quote link outside the part you trying to fade

Comment: I have a new problem now.  The position of the button has changed and now there is a padding on top if the div.http://demo.gbaus.com/index.html

Comment: what did you do ? the button disapeared ?

Comment: It's okey , just be sure the Quote Section has float left, and the link has float right

Comment: check now.  I got the button in the right position but there is padding above the button now?

Comment: class SLIDER has 167px padding top ?

Comment: it fixed for me , just cut down the 167px padding top of div class Slider, if your problem solved you can accept the answer

Comment: and as a note you are using ALOT of Unneccessary DIV's and tags, you can do the same thing with half of them

Comment: Sorry one last thing.  I cant seem to get the button move to the front.  Right now i cant click it unless i click the very bottom.

Comment: something is on it , just make sure set the whole quote section , all the divs float left

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **jQuery** in this case. According to your source every time the slider changes it's image a new link ( tag) is created with new **href** attribute. That's why the link fades in and out with the image having an effect of jQuery.

But you can solve this.

***1.*** Keep a single link as your button and change the **href** attribute with the change of images.

***2.*** Take an array to keep all the link's or **href**.

***3.*** On every image change only change the **href** attribute.